# What use are spirit magic spells for a Shaman?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, shaman

A [Shaman](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/shaman/) has to choose a spirit, in my case [Life](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/shaman/spirits/life/), which in turn grants them a list of spells.
Since a Shaman can prepare any spell from their [spell list](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/spell-lists-and-domains/shaman/#p5) (provided they can cast spells of that level), they do not have to research or otherwise learn a specific spell.

In my concrete example, the Life spirit grants the Shaman the 5th level spell "[Breath of Life](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/breath-of-life/)", but this spell is on the Shaman list anyways? Is this a mistake, just "useless" or am I interpreting something wrong?

As far as I understand the way spirit magic works, I don't get to cast spirit magic any differently than I would cast a normal spell (e.g. not counting against my daily limit)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that the spells from Spirit Magic are in addition to the normal prepared spells. Thus they do not count against your normal spells per day:

> A shaman can spontaneously cast a limited number of spells per day **beyond those she prepared ahead of time**. She has one spell slot per day of each shaman spell level she can cast, not including orisons. 
>   (emphasis mine)

Comment: So for a 5th level Shaman who can cast 3rd level spells, I just get to cast detect undead, lesser restoration and neutralize poison, each once per day, in addition to my prepared spells?

Comment: @MechMK1 Yes but it is slightly more versatile than that since the feature says you get a slot of each level so you could also choose to use detect undead three times, for example, or apply metamagic feats.

Comment: Once you get your wandering spirit you get the spells from that, too. So you have two spells to choose from for each spell level.